# Why doesn't plt.hist() normalization work as expected?

Tags: python, matplotlib

I wrote this code:

```
num_of_points = 10000
Xvec = np.random.uniform(0, 1, num_of_points)
X1 = np.sum(Xvec < 0.3)
X2 = np.sum(np.logical_and(Xvec >= 0.3, Xvec < 5/6))
X3 = np.sum(Xvec >= 5/6)
X = np.hstack([np.zeros(X1), np.ones(X2), np.ones(X3)*2])

plt.hist(X, bins, density=True)
plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [0.3, 0.5, 1/6], 'ro')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

and got this results:

[image: graph of histogram]

Why is the result normalized when setting `density=True`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is unclear what the variable `bins` in the question contains.

With only 3 values on the x-axis, logical bin bounds would be -0.5, 0.5, 1.5 and 2.5. In that case the histogram would be nicely normalized such that heights will sum to one (`0.3 + 8/15 + 1/6 = 1`).

```py
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

num_of_points = 10000
Xvec = np.random.uniform(0, 1, num_of_points)
X1 = np.sum(Xvec < 0.3)
X2 = np.sum(np.logical_and(Xvec >= 0.3, Xvec < 5/6))
X3 = np.sum(Xvec >= 5/6)
X = np.hstack([np.zeros(X1), np.ones(X2), np.ones(X3)*2])
bins=[-0.5,0.5,1.5,2.5]
plt.hist(X, bins, density=True)
plt.plot([0, 1, 2], [0.3, 0.5, 1/6], 'ro')
plt.grid()
plt.show()
```

[image: resulting plot]

Note that a normalized histogram doesn't mean the bars have to sum to one. Normalization means the total area of all bars together needs to be one. The area of a bar is its width times its height. For example, in case there are 10 evenly spaced bins, and the x-es go from `0` to `2`, all the bins would be `0.2` wide.  This automatic spacing doesn't go very logical together with x-es that are limited to integers, but does work as intended. The bin bounds and the values are returned by `plt.hist` and can be inspected:

```py
values, binbounds, patches = plt.hist(X, 10, density=True)
print(values) # [1.486 0. 0. 0. 0. 2.662 0. 0. 0. 0.852]
print(binbounds) # [0.  0.2 0.4 0.6 0.8 1.  1.2 1.4 1.6 1.8 2. ]
```

The sum of the values is `1.486 + 2.662 + 0.852 = 5.0`. Multiplying with the width of each bin (`0.2`) gets the desired area of `1.0`.

The bin values sum to `1.0` when all the bin widths would be `1`.